# Can (the carrier of) a caller/callee see the position of the other ones mobile phone?

Tags: privacy, mobile, phone, tracking

Someone came to me with the following request:

He/She wants to drive somewhere without the employer knowing in his/her free time. If the employer will know about the drive, it will be bad for his/her career. The employer is a big customer of a big mobile phone carrier and therefor has most likely access to all information their carrier has (I once had indirect access to such a carrier portal and know it provides for example information like when your SIM connected to which tower with which signal strength). Therefor the person will not take his/her company provided mobile phone with him/her but a private one. The company also knows the private phone number. The company is also known to spy/track the position via their mobile phones position (GPS/Cell tower/...?) in the past on at least multiple occasions (the position of the mobile phone/employee was told as the reason why the employee was fired/put on probation).

The requester fears for example the company might call his/her private number and get his/her position from their access to their carrier. Is this possible? Are there other ways for the company to get his/her position? Is there a simple way to prevent it (while still using the same mobile phone number)?

Limitations of the question:

- The mobile phone and carrier plan was bought privately in a normal shop not connected to the employer except that his/her supervisor got the mobile phone number for emergencies
- The carrier of the private mobile phone is a different one than the one the employer has access to
- He/She has no apps installed connected to the employer
- He/She does not fetch email addresses known to the employer on the phone nor open any websites/links connected to the company
- The drive will be in the same country, so no roaming involved
- The background noise will not reveal his/her position
- The company should have a barrier from tracking him/her but what happens when they call law enforcements for example to get the information from his/her carrier is outside the question

Comment: If you have access to the carrier itself, you can locate someone without calling them.

Comment: @forest I should have mentioned that the person is using a different carrier or is it possible for a carrier to locate someone from a different carrier?